# Oracle query select statement - count, sum, order by, group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm attempting an Oracle SQL homework assignment that I can't seem to even understand... Can someone give me a hand? I'm not a total noob in SQL, but this one seems too complex for me to understand.

**The prompt is**:
Write a SELECT statement that returns one row for each general ledger account number that contains three columns:
    The account_description column from the General_Ledger_accounts table
    The count of the entries in the Invoice_Line_Items table that have the same account_number
    The sum of the line item amounts in the Invoice_Line_Items table that have the same account_number
Filter the result set to include only those rows with a count greater than 1; group the result set by Account Description (I assume they mean Account_Description); and sort the result set in descending sequence by the sum of the line item amounts.

**Table details**:

```
SQL> desc general_ledger_accounts
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ACCOUNT_NUMBER                            NOT NULL NUMBER
 ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION                       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)
```

Comment: Can you show us your attempted query that is not working?

Comment: I actually haven't even started, because I have no idea where to start. I did ask a classmate, who provided this, but it returns a value of 61482 in the count(distinct invoice_line_items.account_number) column.


select general_ledger_accounts.account_description, count(DISTINCT invoice_line_items.account_number), sum(invoice_line_items.account_number)
from general_ledger_accounts, invoice_line_items
group by general_ledger_accounts.account_description
HAVING count(DISTINCT invoice_line_items.account_number) > 1
order by count(DISTINCT invoice_line_items.account_number) desc;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in your `FROM` clause, you will need to join the `GENERAL_LEDGER_ACCOUNTS` table with the `INVOICE_LINE_ITEMS` table using the condition that `GENERAL_LEDGER_ACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = INVOICE_LINE_ITEMS.ACCOUNT_NUMBER`.

Then (above that), in your `SELECT` clause, indicate the 3 columns you need.

You don't need a `WHERE` clause, since you're considering all the rows.

Use the `GROUP BY` clause to indicate the columns that you want to aggregate over.  Since you want aggregates (a `COUNT` and a `SUM`) for each `ACCOUNT_NUMBER`, then you just want `ACCOUNT_NUMBER` in your `GROUP BY`.

Next, use `HAVING` to filter the groups.  In your case, you want groups `HAVING` a `COUNT` above a certain threshold.

Finally, use `ORDER BY` to order the groups by the `SUM` in `DESC`ending order.

*** SPOILER: TRY TO WORK IT OUT YOURSELF FIRST ***

```
SELECT gla.account_description, count(*), sum(ili.line_item_amount)
FROM   general_ledger_accounts gla
INNER JOIN invoice_line_items ili ON ili.account_number = gla.account_number
GROUP BY gla.account_description
HAVING count(*) > 1
ORDER BY SUM(ili.line_item_amount) DESC
```

Comment: Thank you! Just a few questions, how does the 'count(*)' know to count the entries from only ili, since we say 'FROM gla'?
What's the difference between 'inner join' and 'join'? Both seem to have worked the same way.
Maybe I should have just taken the prompt and did one part at a time. I was just overwhelmed with it.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` counts the total number of records in each group.  I am assuming `ACCOUNT_NUMBER` is the primary key in `GENERAL_LEDGER_ACCOUNTS`.  So, there can be only 1 account in `GENERAL_LEDGER_ACCOUNTS` with `ACCOUNT_NUMBER`, say, 1234.  Suppose there are 6 `ili` rows with that same account number.  Then, the join between `gla` and `ili` will produce 6 rows having account number 1234.  If it were possible for there to be, say, 2 accounts in `gla` with account number 1234, then the join would have produced 2x6=12 rows (and my query wouldn't be correct).  But that's why you always have a...

Comment: foreign key in one table going to a unique key (hopefully the primary key) in another table... to avoid that 2x6 type of situation (called a Cartesian product of a cross product).

Comment: There's no difference between a `JOIN` and an `INNER JOIN`.  A `JOIN` by default is an `INNER JOIN`, which is different from an `OUTER JOIN`, which you'll no doubt learn about later on.

Comment: Matthew, I cannot thank you enough. That was clear and I actually understand it.